# Remove the inscription on the background

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, google-play-services

How to remove this inscription in the background? I wish that I had only Dialog

```
     if(status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {

         } else { 

           int requestCode = 10;
           Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
           dialog.show();
         }
```

[image]

as here
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO I think you cannot do much about it. 
Maybe one workaround would be to make the dialog cover the whole screen (inflate a custom layout).
Just my two pennies.

Comment: Yes you are right. I am not aware of this. Maybe reverse-engineering hangout would help :P